# How to add an onclick event to a joint.js element?

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I have a joint.js element in a DAG, and would like to be able to trigger an event by clicking on it.

I could use `$(selector).click(...)` to do it, but I was wondering if there was a joint.js specific way of handling it,
since that would probobly be better. One event I decided was a candidate for onclick was 'batch:stop'

My code:

```
 var variable =  new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
     name : label,
     id: label,
     onclick : function () {alert("hello");},
     size: { width: width, height: height },
     attrs: {
         text: { text: label, 'font-size': letterSize, 'font-family': 'monospace' },
         rect: {
             fill : fillColor, 
             width: width, height: height,
             rx: 5, ry: 5,
             stroke: '#555'
         }   
     }   
 }); 
 variable.on('batch:stop', function (element) {alert(""); toggleEvidence(element.name);});
 return variable;
```

How should I add an onclick event?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The JointJS shapes are models, so you're right that click handlers won't work on them. The JointJS paper triggers events that might be useful to you:

```
paper.on('cell:pointerdown', 
    function(cellView, evt, x, y) { 
        alert('cell view ' + cellView.model.id + ' was clicked'); 
    }
);
```

other events are: cell:pointerup, cell:pointerdblclick, cell:pointermove.

The complete list can be found here: [http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Paper:events](http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Paper%3aevents).

**EDIT**:

Starting from JointJS v0.9, there is also a `cell:pointerclick` event.

Comment: Thanks. I was reading the wrong aspect of the event documentation, since I thought it would be related to the Element object.

Comment: @dave could you please this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794098/error-while-fetching-json-from-database

Comment: I am trying to trigger a function when an html link inside the jointjs element is clicked . How can that be done ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Backbone itself to attach specific events to specific models. JointJS is just Backbone under the hood.

```
const newElement = new jointjs.shapes.devs.Model({....});
graph.addCell(newElement);

newElement
  .findView(paper)
  .$el.find('.Settings') // this is nested in the model / cell
  .click(() => {
    // do something
  });
```