# Error while fetching json from database

Tags: jointjs

I am able to send data to db using the following:

```
$("#set").click(function ()
                {
                    var cells = graph.getCell();
                    var StateObject = graph.toJSON();
                    var SavedState = JSON.stringify(StateObject);
                    console.log("Here is the state object " + StateObject);
                    console.log("Here is the saved state: " + SavedState);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'JsonProcessor.do',
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            test: StateObject
                        }
                    });
                });
```

But while fetching I get error in chrome console like this:

**Uncaught Error: Graph JSON must contain cells array**

Code to fetch data:

```
$("#get").click(function ()
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'JsonProcessor.do',
                        type: 'get',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            var result = data;
                            console.log("Result from Database: " + result);
                            graph.fromJSON(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

I can see the object fetched in chrome console like this: `[object Object]` and when I expand it

```
`0: Object
JSON_Diagram: "test=%5B%7B%22empID%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22cells%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22basic.Rect%22%2C%22position%22%3A%7B%22x%22%3A-2%2C%22y%22%3A33%7D%2C%22size%22%3A%7B%22width%22%3A71%2C%22height%22%3A625%7D%2C%22angle%22%3A0%2C%22isInteractive%22%3Afalse%2C%22id%22%3A%22ca4cc8a8-7e95-43cb-a8d3-8cf24c82d43f%22%2C%22z%22%3A1%2C%22embeds%22%3A%5B%22b6aee295-16fa-41e7-b25e-d20610cbd631%22%2C%2288de9a15-cbc8-4c02-a358-30491d50cb37%22%5D%2C%22attrs%22%3A%7B%22rect%22%3A%7B%22fill%22%3A%22%23EEEEEE%22%2C%22stroke%22%3A%22%23008B8B%22%2C%22stroke-width%22%3A2%7D%2C%22.%22%3A%7B%22magnet%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22basic.Circle%22%2C%22size%22%3A%7B%22width%22%3A53%2C%22height%22%3A53%7D%2C%22position%22%3A%7B%22x%22%3A8%2C%22y%22%3A130%7D%2C%22angle%22%3A0%2C%22isInteractive%22%3Afalse%2C%22id%22%3A%22b145b765-a60b-4742-82a6-712da89e4dd0%22%2C%22z%22%3A3%2C%22attrs%22%3A%7B%22.%22%3A%7B%22magnet%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22circle1%22%3A%7B%22fill%22%3A%22white%22%2C%22stroke-width%22%3A2%2C%22stroke%22%3A%22green%22%7D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22basic.Circle%22%2C%22size%22%3A%7B%22width%22%3A53%2C%22height%22%3A53%7D%2C%22position%22%3A%7B%22x%22%3A8%2C%22y%22%3A225%7D%2C%22angle%22%3A0%2C%22isInteractive%22%3Afalse%2C%22id%22%3A%221b99b595-57cd-4127-9ec0-d5842beb183a%22%2C%22z%22%3A4%2C%22attrs%22%3A%7B%22.%22%3A%7B%22magnet%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22circle2%22%3A%7B%22fill%22%3A%22white%22%2C%22stroke%22%3A%22green%22%7D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22basic.Circle%22%2C%22size%22%3A%7B%22width%22%3A53%2C%22height%22%3A53%7D%2C%22position%22%3A%7B%22x%22%3A8%2C%22y%22%3A320%7D%2C%22angle%22%3A0%2C%22isInteractive%22%3Afalse%2C%22id%22%3A%227e953c11-d361-44d0-bf29-3d3fa146519c%22%2C%22z%22%3A5%2C%22attrs%22%3A%7B%22.%22%3A%7B%22magnet%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22circle3%22%3A%7B%22fill%22%3A%22white%22%2C%22stroke%22%3A%22green%22%7D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22basic.Rect%22%2C%22position%22%3A%7B%22x%22%3A35%2C%22y%22%3A505%7D%2C%22size%22%3A%7B%22width%22%3A55%2C%22height%22%3A55%7D%2C%22angle%22%3A0%2C%22isInteractive%22%3Afalse%2C%22id%22%3A%22186a6dd7-2b5e-48d6-8e35-ee821ebbb4dc%22%2C%22z%22%3A7%2C%22attrs%22%3A%7B%22rect%22%3A%7B%22fill%22%3A%22%23FFED6B%22%2C%22stroke%22%3A%22%23DBCB62%22%2C%22width%22%3A55%2C%22height%22%3A55%2C%22stroke-width%22%3A1%2C%22transform%22%3A%22rotate(45)%22%7D%2C%22.%22%3A%7B%22magnet%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22basic.Rect%22%2C%22position%22%3A%7B%22x%22%3A10%2C%22y%22%3A50%7D%2C%22size%22%3A%7B%22width%22%3A51%2C%22height%22%3A41%7D%2C%22angle%22%3A0%2C%22isInteractive%22%3Afalse%2C%22id%22%3A%22b6aee295-16fa-41e7-b25e-d20610cbd631%22%2C%22z%22%3A9%2C%22parent%22%3A%22ca4cc8a8-7e95-43cb-a8d3-8cf24c82d43f%22%2C%22attrs%22%3A%7B%22rect%22%3A%7B%22fill%22%3A%22%23D6F2FC%22%2C%22stroke%22%3A%22%237E7E7E%22%7D%2C%22.%22%3A%7B%22magnet%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22basic.Rect%22%2C%22position%22%3A%7B%22x%22%3A10%2C%22y%22%3A420%7D%2C%22size%22%3A%7B%22width%22%3A51%2C%22height%22%3A41%7D%2C%22angle%22%3A0%2C%22isInteractive%22%3Afalse%2C%22id%22%3A%2288de9a15-cbc8-4c02-a358-30491d50cb37%22%2C%22z%22%3A12%2C%22parent%22%3A%22ca4cc8a8-7e95-43cb-a8d3-8cf24c82d43f%22%2C%22attrs%22%3A%7B%22.%22%3A%7B%22magnet%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22rectGroup0%22%3A%7B%22fill%22%3A%22white%22%2C%22stroke%22%3A%22%237E7E7E%22%7D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22devs.Model%22%2C%22size%22%3A%7B%22width%22%3A751%2C%22height%22%3A170%7D%2C%22inPorts%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22outPorts%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22position%22%3A%7B%22x%22%3A160%2C%22y%22%3A123%7D%2C%22angle%22%3A0%2C%22id%22%3A%2237a88170-4da8-464d-99f9-32b72097c495%22%2C%22z%22%3A14%2C%22embeds%22%3A%5B%22e70977f4-52b0-4fdb-a852-8b3b63a5273e%22%5D%2C%22attrs%22%3A%7B%22.label%22%3A%7B%22text%22%3A%22CONTAINER%22%2C%22ref-y%22%3A0.1%2C%22y-alignment%22%3A%22middle%22%7D%2C%22rect%22%3A%7B%22fill%22%3A%22%22%2C%22opacity%22%3A%220.60%22%7D%7D%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22devs.Model%22%2C%22size%22%3A%7B%22width%22%3A51%2C%22height%22%3A41%7D%2C%22inPorts%22%3A%5B%22%22%5D%2C%22outPorts%22%3A%5B%22%22%5D%2C%22position%22%3A%7B%22x%22%3A234%2C%22y%22%3A187%7D%2C%22angle%22%3A0%2C%22id%22%3A%22e70977f4-52b0-4fdb-a852-8b3b63a5273e%22%2C%22z%22%3A15%2C%22parent%22%3A%2237a88170-4da8-464d-99f9-32b72097c495%22%2C%22attrs%22%3A%7B%22.%22%3A%7B%22magnet%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22.port-body%22%3A%7B%22r%22%3A3%7D%2C%22.label%22%3A%7B%22text%22%3A%22%22%2C%22ref-x%22%3A0.4%2C%22ref-y%22%3A0.2%7D%2C%22rect%22%3A%7B%22fill%22%3A%22%23D6F2FC%22%2C%22stroke%22%3A%22%237E7E7E%22%7D%2C%22.inPorts+circle%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22input%22%7D%2C%22.outPorts+circle%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22output%22%7D%2C%22.inPorts%3E.port0%3E.port-label%22%3A%7B%22text%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22.inPorts%3E.port0%3E.port-body%22%3A%7B%22port%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22in29%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22in%22%7D%7D%2C%22.inPorts%3E.port0%22%3A%7B%22ref%22%3A%22.body%22%2C%22ref-y%22%3A0.5%7D%2C%22.outPorts%3E.port0%3E.port-label%22%3A%7B%22text%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%22.outPorts%3E.port0%3E.port-body%22%3A%7B%22port%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22out30%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22out%22%7D%7D%2C%22.outPorts%3E.port0%22%3A%7B%22ref%22%3A%22.body%22%2C%22ref-y%22%3A0.5%2C%22ref-dx%22%3A0%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%5D"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]`
```

but problem is rendering the data on to view in jointjs

Please help if any body have already worked it out.

Comment: kittu can you change your console.log to read `console.log("Result from Database: ", result);` and then see the output in console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key called `JSON_Diagram` is appended to json array when retrieving it. Json sent via ajax call must return exact json for the graph to render the diagram. You need to fix your `JsonProcessor.do` servlet to return same json. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

JointJS' `fromJSON` expects an input of the format `{ cells: [...] }`. So I suspect that if you're saving your JSON using `{ test: JSON.stringify }` you will need to `JSON.parse(result.data)` and then pass it to `graph.fromJSON`.

Final solution

`graph.fromJSON(JSON.parse(result.data))`

Comment: I tried your answer. Its giving error like this: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u$.click.$.ajax.success @ index.jsp:333jQuery.Callbacks.fire @ joint.js:2920jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith @ joint.js:3032done @ joint.js:7407jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback @ joint.js:7829XMLHttpRequest.send (async)jQuery.ajaxTransport.send @ joint.js:7852jQuery.extend.ajax @ joint.js:7308(anonymous function) @ index.jsp:327jQuery.event.dispatch @ joint.js:4683jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle @ joint.js:4367`

Comment: kittu, can you print the output of `console.log(result)` (note no preceding string in the output)?

Comment: `console.log("Result from Database: ", result);` prints the result in form of object. I can see the json string in the object

Comment: How do I do graph.fromJson now to get the view on screen?

Comment: output of result in console is like this: `>[Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: Waiting for your reply. Is some thing with the code or is it a bug?

Comment: kittu, looks like your `result` has 4 items (an array), with the first one being the json blob. So you will need to grab it using `JSON.parse(result[0])`. See if that works. 

In the event it doesn't, I would recommend removing JSON.stringify when saving, because it will anyway get stringified "over the wire" by the browser. And make your job easier when you load it to see which part of result to grab.

Comment: I tried `JSON.parse(result[0])` already. Will try without stringify and see. By the way `graph.fromJSON` is supposed to render diagram in to view right?

Comment: yes, as long as the parameter is the same as the value you got from `graph.toJSON()`.